# Optimize InitContent Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a marketplace with prestashop but my back office is slow (about 15s).

Consequently, I did

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);
```

[image: Results]

And I saw that this f******* gamification module took a lot of memory consequently I deleted it.

But I see that initContent is very slow (about 15s) **consequently I want to know if you have some advices on how optimize it ?**

Comment: Online or local installation?

Comment: It's on a virtual machine linux debian (it's for a university) but the website is not online yet.

Comment: Probably it's all correlated at the hardware of the vm. 15s it's a very long time, above all if is the backoffice. Have you installed a template?

Comment: Yes I've installed the Nordstorm template http://addons.prestashop.com/fr/22821-nordstorm-men-s-wear.html

Comment: Try to make a new clean installation, also in a subfolder it's ok. If the backoffice loads in 15s therefore the problem it's the configuration of the vm.

Comment: I agree with @sarcom try a fresh install and benchmark it, it should be pretty fast. You can remove gamification without problems, also remove the demo mode.